# Image File Saved on Android Device Not Opening

Tags: android, image, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to display an image and some HTML associated with it in a WebView.  I get the image as byte[].  I am creating a .PNG file using the following code.

```
private string CreatePNG(byte[] data)
    {
        string filePath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
        string fileName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), data);
        return Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    }
```

Then I embed the .PNG file in my HTML using the following code.

```
html += @"<img src=""file://" + CreatePNG(page.DocumentImage) + "\"/><br><br>";
```

The image shows as blank in my app.  The text shows properly.  If I try to open the image directly on the phone after browsing from "File Manager", it still shows as blank.  When I copy the image from the phone to my Mac, it opens up fine.

Can someone please advise what is going wrong here?

Comment: `CreatePNG(page.DocumentImage)` ??? Who knows what that is? You should post here the exact path. The result. And also tell how you loaded the html file to begin with.

Comment: What is the file size of your png file?

Comment: `I get the image as byte[].`. From who? From where?

Comment: Can you open the file on a Windows PC ? Can you please place the file on the internet and give a url?

Comment: `I am creating a .PNG file using the following code.`. You are creating a file with a filename having extension .png. If it is really a png file we dont know.

Comment: 1. page.DocumentImage is a byte[] which expected by CreatePNG function.
2. Size of file is less than 1 MB.
3. byte[] comes from a service.
4. As mentioned, I can open the file on Mac after copying it from phone.
5. The byte[] is in fact a PNG as the file created using the byte[] can be opened on Mac.

Comment: You are not giving the info i asked for. And if it is indead a png file it should be openable on Android too. Your response does not make sense.